# I wrote an if condition inside angularjs controller, not working properly

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

I wrote this if statement by myself to differentiate USD and LKR, the values are not coming properly. Is this if condition correct?

```
$scope.$watch('currencyVal', function () {
                            if ($scope.currencyVal === "USD") {
                                 if ($scope.shipping_method === "pronto") {
                                     if($scope.weight >= 1){                                    
                                         $scope.output = '101';
                                     }
                                     else 
                                     {                        
                                      $scope.output = '102';
                                     }
                                 }else
                                 {                      
                                     $scope.output = '103';
                                 }

                            } else if ($scope.currencyVal !== "USD") {

                                if ($scope.shipping_method === "pronto") {
                                     if($scope.weight >= 1){                                      
                                        $scope.output = '104';
                                     }
                                     else 
                                     {
                                        $scope.output = '105';
                                     }
                                }
                                else{
                                            $scope.output = '106';
                                }
                            }

                        });
```

Comment: The if-statements itself seems fine, although a bit weird. What do you mean with "the values are not coming properly"? How does the error present itself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking to do, but based off of your code, I put together a working controller that will output a value based on those three inputs:

```
$scope.data = {
    currencyVal: 'USD',
    shippingMethod: 'pronto',
    weight: 1,
    output: function() {
        ...
    }
};
```

http://codepen.io/bluwoh/pen/ENZQvb?editors=1010